# how to pad a text after build the vocab in pytorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I used torchtext vocab to convert the text to index, but which function should I use to make all the index list be the same length before I send them to the net?

For example I have 2 texts:

```
I am a good man
I would like a coffee please
```

After vocab:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 7]
[1, 9, 6, 2, 4, 8]
```

And what I want is:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 0]
[1, 9, 6, 2, 4, 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to understand by looking at the following example.

Code:

```py
import torch

v = [
        [0,2],
        [0,1,2],
        [3,3,3,3]
]

torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence([torch.tensor(p) for p in v], batch_first=True)
```

Result:

```py
tensor([[0, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 2, 0],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```